# How to add Picasso Library

Tags: android, gridview, picasso

I have a gridview, When any item in gridview is clicked the image zooms in and comes to the center of the screen, swiping left and right changes the images in the imageview. This was the mechanism of the app.

The images are present in drawable folders but i want to fetch them from URLs, for this purpose i am using Picasso library.

I have imported the jar file of picasso library in my the libs folder, network permissions added in the manifest, all i am left with is changes in my MainActivity.

I was using "int" for initializing the images, now how can i replace those images with URLs.

Here is my code:

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GridView gv;
    private Animator mCurrentAnimator;
    private int mShortAnimationDuration;
    private int j = 0;

    private final GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(
            new SwipeGestureDetector());
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;

    // Create Array thumbs resource id's:
    private int thumb[] = { R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three,
            R.drawable.four, R.drawable.five, R.drawable.six, R.drawable.seven,
            R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.three, R.drawable.four,
            R.drawable.five, R.drawable.six, R.drawable.seven,
            R.drawable.eight, R.drawable.one };

    private ImageView expandedImageView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize the variables:
        gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        // Set an Adapter to the ListView
        gv.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        // Set on item click listener to the ListView
        gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int pos,
                    long id) {

                // Display the zoomed in image in full screen
                j = pos;
                zoomImageFromThumb(v, thumb[pos]);

            }
        });

        // Set the Animation time form the android defaults
        mShortAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(
                android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

    }

    // Create an Adapter Class extending the BaseAdapter
    class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public ImageAdapter(MainActivity activity) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Set the count value to the total number of items in the Array
            return thumb.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            // Inflate the item layout and set the views
            View listItem = convertView;
            int pos = position;
            if (listItem == null) {
                listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
            }

            // Initialize the views in the layout
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.thumb);

            // Set the views in the layout
            iv.setBackgroundResource(thumb[pos]);

            return listItem;
        }

    }

    private void zoomImageFromThumb(final View thumbView, int imageResId) {
        // If there's an animation in progress, cancel it immediately and
        // proceed with this one.
        if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
            mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
        }

        // Load the high-resolution "zoomed-in" image.
        expandedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.expanded_image);

        expandedImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (detector.onTouchEvent(event))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
        });

        expandedImageView.setImageResource(imageResId);

        // Calculate the starting and ending bounds for the zoomed-in image.
        // This step
        // involves lots of math. Yay, math.
        final Rect startBounds = new Rect();
        final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
        final Point globalOffset = new Point();

        // The start bounds are the global visible rectangle of the thumbnail,
        // and the
        // final bounds are the global visible rectangle of the container view.
        // Also
        // set the container view's offset as the origin for the bounds, since
        // that's
        // the origin for the positioning animation properties (X, Y).
        thumbView.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBounds);
        findViewById(R.id.container).getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds,
                globalOffset);
        startBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
        finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);

        // Adjust the start bounds to be the same aspect ratio as the final
        // bounds using the
        // "center crop" technique. This prevents undesirable stretching during
        // the animation.
        // Also calculate the start scaling factor (the end scaling factor is
        // always 1.0).
        float startScale;
        if ((float) finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height() > (float) startBounds
                .width() / startBounds.height()) {
            // Extend start bounds horizontally
            startScale = (float) startBounds.height() / finalBounds.height();
            float startWidth = startScale * finalBounds.width();
            float deltaWidth = (startWidth - startBounds.width()) / 2;
            startBounds.left -= deltaWidth;
            startBounds.right += deltaWidth;
        } else {
            // Extend start bounds vertically
            startScale = (float) startBounds.width() / finalBounds.width();
            float startHeight = startScale * finalBounds.height();
            float deltaHeight = (startHeight - startBounds.height()) / 2;
            startBounds.top -= deltaHeight;
            startBounds.bottom += deltaHeight;
        }

        // Hide the thumbnail and show the zoomed-in view. When the animation
        // begins,
        // it will position the zoomed-in view in the place of the thumbnail.
        thumbView.setAlpha(0f);
        expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Set the pivot point for SCALE_X and SCALE_Y transformations to the
        // top-left corner of
        // the zoomed-in view (the default is the center of the view).
        expandedImageView.setPivotX(0f);
        expandedImageView.setPivotY(0f);

        // Construct and run the parallel animation of the four translation and
        // scale properties
        // (X, Y, SCALE_X, and SCALE_Y).
        AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
        set.play(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X,
                        startBounds.left, finalBounds.left))
                .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y,
                        startBounds.top, finalBounds.top))
                .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X,
                        startScale, 1f))
                .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_Y,
                        startScale, 1f));
        set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
        set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mCurrentAnimator = null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                mCurrentAnimator = null;
            }
        });
        set.start();
        mCurrentAnimator = set;

        // Upon clicking the zoomed-in image, it should zoom back down to the
        // original bounds
        // and show the thumbnail instead of the expanded image.
        final float startScaleFinal = startScale;
        expandedImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
                    mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
                }

                // Animate the four positioning/sizing properties in parallel,
                // back to their
                // original values.
                AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
                set.play(
                        ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X,
                                startBounds.left))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y,
                                startBounds.top))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView,
                                View.SCALE_X, startScaleFinal))
                        .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView,
                                View.SCALE_Y, startScaleFinal));
                set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
                set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                        expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mCurrentAnimator = null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                        thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                        expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mCurrentAnimator = null;
                    }
                });
                set.start();
                mCurrentAnimator = set;
            }
        });
    }

    private class SwipeGestureDetector extends
            GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {
            try {
                if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                    if (thumb.length > j) {
                        j++;

                        if (j < thumb.length) {
                            expandedImageView.setImageResource(thumb[j]);
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            j = 0;
                            expandedImageView.setImageResource(thumb[j]);
                            return true;
                        }

                    }
                } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                    if (j > 0) {
                        j--;
                        expandedImageView.setImageResource(thumb[j]);
                        return true;

                    } else {
                        j = thumb.length - 1;
                        expandedImageView.setImageResource(thumb[j]);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

When i am trying to covert the drawable initializing from int to string like this:

```
private String[] thumb = new String[] {

        "http://i1040.photobucket.com/albums/b406/Aleem_Ahmed/seven-min_zpsdnohn4io.png",
        "http://i1040.photobucket.com/albums/b406/Aleem_Ahmed/one-min_zpsxdzul6kt.png",
        "http://i1040.photobucket.com/albums/b406/Aleem_Ahmed/two-min_zpsgsjz8ugv.png",
        "http://i1040.photobucket.com/albums/b406/Aleem_Ahmed/three-min_zpshzlif6si.png",
        "http://i1040.photobucket.com/albums/b406/Aleem_Ahmed/six-min_zpsfx9d2dse.png",
        "http://i1040.photobucket.com/albums/b406/Aleem_Ahmed/four-min_zpsqlpatblc.png",
        "http://i1040.photobucket.com/albums/b406/Aleem_Ahmed/five-min_zps4ouhgigl.png",
        "http://i1040.photobucket.com/albums/b406/Aleem_Ahmed/eight-min_zpsnr9cdgga.png",

};
```

Than the code shows the following errors:

```
The method zoomImageFromThumb(View, int) in the type MainActivity is not applicable for the arguments (View, String)

The method setImageResource(int) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (String)
```

What am i missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you using Picasso library? I am unable to find it here in the code

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra You mean this code? Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra Well, i am unable to figure out where and how to put it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Picasso like this -

```
Picasso.with(this)
   .load("YOUR IMAGE URL HERE")
   .into(imageView);
```

Just put it, where you need to set the image.

Comment: Put it in place of  iv.setBackgroundResource(thumb[pos]);

Comment: But i have more than one image

Comment: I mean i have multiple URLs and i am making a string of them

Comment: Use thumb[pos] as your url

Comment: Solved the problem myself. Thanks for the help though, your answer gave me an idea to think like that and you deserve your answer to be accepted so here it goes.

Comment: That is  my Pleasure :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76698/discussion-between-milly-corsh-and-droidworm-narendra).